# Basis of $\{0\}$ set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am solving Linear Algebra and having a trivial doubt .

`Is W ={∅} i.e. an empty set a basis of ={0} ?`

I have read some solutions regarding the above and they imply that since W contains no vector , W  by definition is linearly independent .
I am not sure how W spans V. Can anyone explain this to me ?

```
"Every vector space has a basis."
```

Is the above statement true ?

Comment: I'm assuming you did not expect this, but the statement "Every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents). Things get messy when they are infinite.

Comment: @CameronWilliams , zero vector can't be basis because it is linearly dependent.

Comment: Note that usually one defines the empty sum to be $0$, so with this understood the empty set does form a generating set of the trivial vector space.

Comment: The zero vector by itself is not linearly independent because $k0=0$ has nonzero solutions. By convention, a sum of no items is zero - consider the sum of three things, then remove them one at a time.  So the sum of no numbers is the number zero, while the sum of no vectors is the zero vector.

Comment: Using the (perhaps more elegant) definition of the span of a subset as the smallest subspace containing the subset, it is also true that the empty set spans the trivial vector space, regardless of any conventions regarding empty sums.

Comment: No, $\{\emptyset\}$ is not a basis for anything - it's not even a set of vectors. But $\emptyset$ _is_ a basis for $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard convention for any binary operation with a neutral element is that the "empty operation" gives the neutral element. Some specific examples:

- The empty sum is $0$: $\sum_{x\in\emptyset}x=0$.
- The empty product is $1$: $\prod_{x\in\emptyset}x=1$.
- The empty union is the empty set: $\bigcup_{A\in\emptyset}A=\emptyset$.

Important for your question is the first one in the list: A linear combination of vectors in the empty set is the zero vector:

$$\sum_{v\in W}a_vv=\sum_{v\in\emptyset}a_v v=0.$$

And thus $W=\emptyset$ (not $\{\emptyset\}$!) spans the trivial vector space. It is also linearly independent, since there is no non-trivial linear combination which results in the zero vector.

Comment: +1 and I have to correct my above comment, $\emptyset$ does span the trivial space by the empty operation

Comment: nicely explained , thanks Vercassivelaunos

Answer (score 5):

If $V=\{0\}$ - a trivial vector space, then $W=\emptyset$ is its basis. (Note: *not* $W=\{\emptyset\}$ but $W=\emptyset=\{\}$.)

This empty set spans $V$ because any sum of *no* addends is taken, by convention, to be zero (in this case a zero vector).

This also matches the alternative definition of a span: "the smallest subspace containing all the vectors from the set". In this case, any subspace (including $\{0\}$) vacuously contains all the vectors from the empty set.

Comment: I get the point . Let us now take for the fact that W = ∅ is basis of V = {0} as ∅ spans V and is Linearly Independent. But we know that any span is also a subspace. How do you explain that ∅ is a subspace as it doesn't contain identity element.

Comment: $W$ is empty. Its span is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks , understood my fault !!

Comment: What should be the dimension of W = ∅ then ?

Comment: You can speak of *size* / *cardinality* of $W$ and of *dimension* of $V$. The dimension of the vector space is the size/cardinality of any of its bases. In this case, the size of an empty set is $|W|=0$, so $\dim V=0$.